# Customize the size of the shaded box

Tags: margins, framed, shading

I am using `\begin{shaded}` from `\usepackage{framed}`.

The problem is I am using it for examples which come inside `\begin{itemize}`, the shaded box's margin does not begin with the `\item` margin instead the shaded color begins from far left.

[image: The screenshot from my document]

**I would like to have it like the below image -**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package `framed` uses the command `\centerline` which always starts at the outer left margin. I recommend to switch to the new package `tcolorbox`.

Comment: May I ask you why didn't you also suggested `mdframed`?